# How do I change the order in the query result in sql (Oracle)

Tags: sql

I am using following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT DECODE(om.value, 'NAN', '0', om.value) value,
    om.date_time,
    om.name,
    om.measurement_id
  FROM ems.Observation o,
    ems.Observation_Measurement om
  WHERE o.Observation_Id = om.Observation_Id
  AND o.co_mod_asset_id  =1240
  AND om.measurement_id IN (2109,2110)
  ORDER BY om.DATE_TIME DESC
  )
WHERE rownum <= 8
```

and the output is attached in the image.[image].

I need to change the order of the WIND_DIR and WIND_SPD so that WIND_SPD comes first and then WIND_DIR. The expected output result will be:

```
WIND_SPD
WIND_DIR
WIND_SPD
WIND_DIR
WIND_SPD
WIND_DIR
WIND_SPD
WIND_DIR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following `order by` to your query:

```
order by date_time desc, measurement_id
```

This assumes that the `date_time` value for both measurements is *exactly* the same, as they appear to be in the output provided.

Actually, you could probably just add `, measurement_id` to the `order by` in the inner query too.